# Core data can't save NSManagedObjectContext

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, core-data

So I parsed a xml and created a bunch of ManagedObjects with relationships like "User has_many Badges", the app can display each user's profile fine with the just parsed data. But if I close the app from the multitask bar and reopen it. The data is gone. No warnings. Where should I start debugging? Thanks. The code goes like this:
 `[self parseXML];
    [appDelegate saveContext];`

Details: Here is how I created core data model: I've used the code from the template from xcode. Every user has many badges but I don't have reverse relationship from badge to user.  Right after I parsed the xml and created all the users with badges, the app could pull data from the context and generate profile views with badges and everything.

The problem:

After I close the app from multitask bar, core data will store all the User properties like projects and telephones, except badges. Badge is a separate entity. Thanks.

Solved: the problem resolved itself after I setup the reverse relationship. Can't think of other reasons might cos the problem if I messed with other code.

Comment: theres not enough info here to even start answering this question, how are you creating your core data objects?

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot to go on but:

If the Core Data object graph works in all ways except it doesn't persist the data then the problem pretty much has to be at the level of the persistent store itself.

(1) Make sure you don't have an in-memory persistent store. As its name suggest, there is nothing persistent about that type of store. The object graph will work, the context will execute a save operation but nothing is ever written to disk. Check the `initWithPersistentStoreCoordinator:configurationName:URL:options` method to see the type and location of the store.

(2) Make you didn't put the store in one of the cache or tmp folder in the app directory. Those folders will be routinely purged.

If you just used the boilerplate from the Xcode templates for a Core Data project, you shouldn't have these problems as the template creates a sqlite persistent store file in the `Documents` directory.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated more details. But I think the store is fine, since it can store all the other properties of the user except the badges property.